# Existence of Simple Closed Straightest Geodesics

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

There are at least three distinct simple closed quasigeodesics on convex polyhedra [Mat. Sb. (N.S.), 1949, 25(67) :2, 275–306 [Quasi-geodesic lines on a convex surface](http://mi.mathnet.ru/msb6003) Pogorelov].

Is the same true for straightest geodesics?

Related Questions:
[the-famous-lusternik-schnirelmann-theorem-of-the-three-closed-geodesics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94174/the-famous-lusternik-schnirelmann-theorem-of-the-three-closed-geodesics)
, [midpoint-geodesic-polygon-birkhoff-curve-shortening](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42352/midpoint-geodesic-polygon-birkhoff-curve-shortening)

Straightest Geodesics:[straightest_preprint.pdf](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/polthier/articles/straightest/straightest_preprint.pdf)

--Thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by *straightest geodesic* you mean: has the same surface angle to either side at every point.
Let the polyhedron $P$ be a doubly covered obtuse triangle $\triangle abc$.
The path $abc$ is a straightest geodesic.
It seems the other quasigeodesics guaranteed by Pogorelov's theorem must pass through vertices, such as that following the
altitude through the obtuse vertex $c$. But this will not be straightest.
The path $aba$ is a quasigeodesic, with less than $\pi$ to each side of every point, but it
is not straightest.

          
[image: TriGeodesic]

So it seems that this "polyhedron" has just one simple (noncrossing), straightest geodesic.

Comment: Thanks! I checked and yep there aren't any others. The followup question is: Is there always at *least* one? 

Comment: After a little thought. I'm pretty sure the answer is *no*. Choose a set of vertices with angle deficits such that no two subsets have the same total angle deficit. The proof should follow.

Comment: I agree, Bryan. In fact, a generic (random) polyhedron would have the property you mention. Nice question; too bad the answer is negative!